# Support deserialization of inheritance chained objects in kotlin with jackson

Tags: kotlin, jackson

Assume we need to comply deserialization of such object inheritance structure:

```
open class Parent(
    @JsonProperty("parent_value")
    val parentValue: String = "default"
)

class Child(
    @JsonProperty("child_value")
    val childValue: String) : Parent()
```

Both parent & child object define own fields and `@JsonProperty` over it.

Also i have a test to check deserialization:

```
@Test
fun testDeserializeWithInheritance() {

    val map = mapOf("child_value" to "success", "parent_value" to "success")

    val jsonResult = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(map)

    println("serialized object: $jsonResult")

    val deserialized: JsonConverterModuleTest.Child = objectMapper.readValue(jsonResult)
    println("deserialized object: withdraw=${deserialized.childValue} parentValue = ${deserialized.parentValue}, exchangeFrom = ${deserialized.parentValue}")

    assertEquals("success", deserialized.childValue)
    assertEquals("success", deserialized.parentValue)
}
```

But a problem is the test fails with error:

> serialized object: {   "child_value" : "success",   "parent_value" :
>   "success" }
>
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: parent value not equal:
>   Expected:success
>   Actual   :default

How to deserialize the child object properly? The main goal is to not duplicate fields nor `@JsonProperty` annotations in child class.

I have a solution for the issue, but open to accept better one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happens because annotation over constructor field is not applied to field nor getter automatically (kotlin mechanizm). Also Seems that it is not processed on deserialization of a child object.
Jackson supports annotations over field or over getter methods, so an appropriate solutions are either

```
open class Parent(
    @get:JsonProperty("parent_value")
    val parentValue: String = "default"
)
```

or

```
open class Parent(
    @field:JsonProperty("parent_value")
    val parentValue: String = "default"
)
```

With this the test completes

Comment: Hi! The annotation #field did the trick for me. But can you explain difference between #get and #field to know when we need to use one instead of the other? Thanks